# Append sequential columns

Tags: matlab, append, reshape

I have a an array size of 50 x 100. What I want to do is to append the second column to the first column, the fourth column to the third, sixth to the 5th etc... so that I have a 100 x 50 matrix. The following example shows what I am trying to do

1 2 3 4 becomes 1 3 and so on
5 6 7 8         5 7
                2 4
                6 8

I looked for a similar question but could not find one

Comment: What have you done? Note that Stack Overflow requires some effort from your side, meaning in this case thoughts on how to proceed, either in pseudocode or actual code, in which case it's called a [mcve]. List any inputs, desired outputs, and errors you got. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example:

```
% Define a sample matrix:
A = [
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12;
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12;
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12;
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12;
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12;
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
];

% Build an index to even rows:
idx_even = mod(1:size(A,2),2) == 0;

% Store the even rows of the matrix in a saparate variable:
A_even = A(:,idx_even);

% Delete the even rows from the original matrix:
A(:,idx_even) = [];

% Append the even rows to the remaining (odd) rows of the original matrix:
A = [A; A_even];
```

Output:

```
A =

     1     3     5     7     9    11
     1     3     5     7     9    11
     1     3     5     7     9    11
     1     3     5     7     9    11
     1     3     5     7     9    11
     1     3     5     7     9    11
     2     4     6     8    10    12
     2     4     6     8    10    12
     2     4     6     8    10    12
     2     4     6     8    10    12
     2     4     6     8    10    12
     2     4     6     8    10    12
```